# Access iOS Voice recognition in app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, voice-recognition, openears

Currently i am using open ears to detect a phrase and it works pretty well, although i would like to recognize all words in the english language and add that to a text field. So I had two thoughts on how to approach this.

1) Somehow load the entire english dictionary into OpenEars. 
(i don't think it is a good idea because they say from 2-300 words or something like that

2)Activate the native iOS voice recognition without deploying the keyboard.

I'm leaning towoards the second way if possible because i love the live recognition in iOS 8, it works flawlessly for me.

How do i recognize all words using one of the two methods (or a better way if you know)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you can't do 1) or 2), at least not the way you want to.  OpenEars won't handle the whole English dictionary, and you can't get iOS voice recognition without the keyboard widget.  You might want to look into Dragon Dictation, which is the speech engine that Siri uses, or SILVIA. You'll have to pay for a license though.

Comment: Do you mean http://silvia4u.info/? As for Dragon Dictation, they seem to belong to Nuance now.